# Styling options for top bar menu actions in react-native-navigation

Tags: react-native-navigation

Are there any styling options to set the top bar menu actions for dark mode? I have set a few buttons as `showAsAction: never` in the `TopBar` and want the menu to follow the app theme. Currently it appears as white as shown in the screenshot.

[image]